# Testlink Jenkins integration- Issue in testlink installation

Tags: jenkins, testlink

I am trying to integrate testlink and jenkins for automated test report logging in testlink. I am using Ant jobs for running the test scripts in jmeter. I am facing issue in installation of testlink. Can i use xampp for installing testlink for jenkins integrations. Or anyother method i need to follow. Kindly help me to sort it out

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the issue that you are facing? You are concealing a lot of information. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am getting the below error when integrating Jenkins with testlink Preparing TestLink client API.
Using TestLink URL: http://localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php

FATAL: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Not Found
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Not Found

Comment: So the URL returns not found. Seems like testlink isn't installed there.

Answer (score 0):

May be the question asked here too old. But am new here

You can use xampp and keep your testlink folder in htdocs folder which is downloaded and extracted

Also, look folder name of test link is correct and matching with the link

http://localhost/testlink-1.9.16/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php

My folder name is testlink-1.9.16